# Images not being shown in footer with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using Jquery mobile.

I have a footer div.

In that div I am wanting to display 2 image buttons.

The buttons appear but the images do not.

This is my mark-up:

```
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <div data-role='footer' data-theme='a' data-position='fixed'>
            <div data-role='navbar' id='kms'>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEnterPIN" runat="server" Height="42px" Width="42px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png"
                                OnClientClick="return false;" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEscape2" runat="server" Height="42px" Width="42px" ImageUrl="~/Images/back_2.png"
                                OnClientClick="return false;" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are the images in the correct path? Do you see any 404 by checking the network console?

Comment: hi, thanks for replying.  Yes they are.  I have even used the full url path and still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using html img instead of asp img it works